# Multi Threading Not Processing all Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing

I am using below code for doing a task using threading, here i am trying execute all the records from the "dtTable" Datatable. with limited thread count of 2(i.e at time only two thread/ Execution only allowed). Problem is its not executing all the records available in Datatable, its executing data's in irregular manner. What might be the problem..? Thanks in Advance.

```
 public class Generator : IDisposable
 {
    public static int maxThreadCount = 2;
    public static int runningThreadCount = 0;

    public RunTask()
    {
       for (int ro = 0; ro <= dtTable.Rows.Count - 1; ro++)
       {
          if (maxThreadCount > runningThreadCount)
          {
            Thread atpthread = new Thread(delegate()
            {
            DoOperationMethod(dtTable.Rows[ro], Task, startDate, EndDate, dtTemplate);
            });
            atpthread.Start();
            runningThreadCount = runningThreadCount + 1;
            Mainthreads.Add(atpthread);
          }
          else
          {
            ro--;
          }
       }
  }

  public void DoOperationMethod(DataRow drAttachpoint, System.StrTaskItem Task, DateTime startDate, DateTime EndDate, DataTable dtTemplate)
    {
     //doing my Operation
     runningThreadCount = runningThreadCount-1; //Once Task done count will get reduce
    }
```

}

I am using .net 3.5(FYI).

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? Chances are it relates to the `runningThreadCount` which appears you are changing simultaneously in multiple threads, but we can't see that code to be sure.

Comment: It also appears that `DoOperationMethod` works directly with the `DataTable`, but since `DataTable` isn't thread-safe you might have problems there. We need to see the code to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for your Enigmativity, I have added rest of code,

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you keep iterating the rows in the datatable while waiting for a thread to become free. In any case, this kind of multithreading, even if it were actually correct (it isn't), is quite inefficient - most of the time is probably spent starting new threads.

Try something like this instead:

```
Parallel
 .ForEach(dtTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>(), row => DoOperationMethod(...))
 .WithDegreeOfParallelism(2);
```

**EDIT:**

To clear up how the problem comes to be, you have to understand how variables are captured in anonymous methods. Your `DoOperationMethod` call is not being passed the data row you want, because the `ro` "variable" is not copied, but rather referenced. So when `ro` changes in the loop, it also changes in the threads you created.

This is apart from the fact that your code is horribly thread-unsafe, and inefficient:

- You're actually wasting *three* threads doing work - with no blocking, your loop just keeps adding and subtracting `ro`, which is almost entirely pure CPU work. That's much more of a waste than simply blocking while waiting for the result.
- You can't just read and write static fields from multiple threads and expect things to work properly. It's actually quite easy for your code to start more threads in parallel than you'd like - or even deadlock the whole thing with `runningThread` ending up being `2`, while no threads are running.
- You keep starting new threads to execute a seemingly trivial operation - I'd guess most of your work is either I/O-bound, or dominated by the cost of creating new threads over and over again.
- I assume `Mainthreads` is a list of some kind, and I assume you also modify it from the `DoOperationMethod` method - again, this can lead to random exceptions and unexpected results.
- In theory, it's even possible that the check `maxThreadCount > runningThreadCount` will never be evaluated, due to various optimizations and caching. In practice, on current .NET on an x86 CPU this isn't exactly likely for a method as complex as this, but it's the kind of thing that can bite you when you update to .NET 7.0 or whatever :)

Multi-threading is *hard*. You really don't want to guess your way around. At the very least, try to understand the basics first - http://www.albahari.com/threading/.

Comment: You say - "The problem is that you keep iterating the rows in the datatable while waiting for a thread to become free." Can you say why this is the problem?

Comment: Sure. The execution of the code in the thread is taking longer than two iterations of the loop (otherwise there would be little point in using multi-threading in the first place). However, this also means that with no waiting, in the time it takes you to "release" a thread (e.g. `runningThreadCount--` or similar; and yeah, I know it's horribly thread-unsafe), you managed to iterate a few of the rows with doing no operation on *them* - that is, they were completely skipped.

Comment: Sorry, I might be being thick, but I don't see how this explains **why**.

Comment: @Enigmativity: the issue is that `ro` is captured by the anonymous method, but its value can change before the thread gets to actually run. E.g. the first two threads are created and started, but they don't actually get CPU time until the loop has incremented `ro` to the value of `2`. So those first two thread process row `2` instead of rows `0` and `1`. To make matters worse, the loop is constantly incrementing and decrementing `ro` while it waits for a thread to be done.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Now that's the issue. Our friend, Luaan, should update their answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Your final bullet point seems highly suspect to me. With the increment in the loop of `runningThreadCount`, I doubt the compiler would ever skip the comparison. It would have to do way too complicated static flow analysis on the loop, and essentially unroll the loop to two iterations. Technically legal, but so likely to break buggy code I doubt it'd ever make it past initial feature review. Other than that, a number of good useful points regarding flaws in the OP's code. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho It would probably need some a bit more dynamic analysis. .NET JIT already does this for a few cases (like virtual method invocation), but yeah, doing something like this is a quite far fetched. It's an easy optimization for a *human* to see, of course - you're only ever incrementing `runningThreadCount` and `maxThreadCount` is never modified, so once `runningThreadCount` is equal to `maxThreadCount` (effectively a constant), it can never ever evaluate to `true` again. Simpler than a full-fledged flow analysis, but yeah, still unlikely to ever be implemented.

Comment: Data table can be used as enumerable type, dtTable.AsEnumerable() using namespace System.Data.DataSetExtensions, no need to access row collection explicitly

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the biggest issue with your code is that, even if you fixed your thread unsafe usage of `runningThreadCount`, your code is "spinning" while waiting for some thread to complete. This completely ties up a CPU core while you're trying to get real work done.

The solution Luann proposes is good, though I would use `Cast<DataRow>()` instead of `OfType<DataRow>()` (since all of the elements in the enumeration are in fact expected to be of the type `DataRow`). One big advantage, other than its conciseness, is that it uses the thread pool, which will significantly reduce the overhead of thread management (since it reuses threads instead of creating and destroying them over and over).

If you prefer a more explicit approach, you can modify the code you posted to use a semaphore:

```
SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(2);

for (int ro = 0; ro <= dtTable.Rows.Count - 1; ro++)
{
    semaphore.Wait();

    DataRow row = dtTable.Rows[ro];

    Thread atpthread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        DoOperationMethod(row, Task, startDate, EndDate, dtTemplate);
        semaphore.Release();
    });
    atpthread.Start();
    Mainthreads.Add(atpthread);
}
```

That will cause the main thread to block on the `Wait()` call when the semamphore count reaches 0, and to continue once the count is positive again (i.e. after a thread calls `Release()`).

I note commenter Enigmativity's point about whether `dtTable` is used safely or not. I'm assuming here that the object is not being modified during this processing. With that assumption, using it unsynchronized should be fine. But if that assumptions false, then I agree with them that that's another bug in the code.

Finally, I'll point out that the reason you see rows being skipped is that you're using the variable `ro` in the anonymous method. That variable can easily be incremented before the anonymous method gets to execute for a given iteration of the loop, causing that thread to process the wrong row. Some rows may be processed multiple times while other rows are skipped. I've addressed the problem in the above code example by retrieving the `DataRow` object in a variable inside the loop block, so that each thread gets its own private copy of the variable, with exactly the `DataRow` object it's supposed to process.

Comment: Hi Peter Duniho, "SemaphoreSlim" will support in .net 3.5 ?

Comment: No. I see nothing in your question that says you are stuck with 3.5, but if you are, you can just use `Semaphore` instead. Works exactly the same (I mean, the syntax is slightly different, but the behavior and features are the same).

Comment: Why `Cast` when anything in the `DataRowCollection` *is* a `DataRow`? The only reason I use `OfType` is to pretend it implements `IEnumerable<DataRow>` :))

Comment: @Luaan: `Cast<T>()` is equivalent to casting (of course), while `OfType<T>()` is equivalent to `as` followed by a check for null. I use `Cast<T>()` instead of `OfType<T>()` for the same reason I use an actual cast instead of `as`; it is semantically correct for the operation at hand. I.e. if I have a bug, an `InvalidCastException()` will be thrown instead of `NullReferenceException`. Using `OfType<T>()` is even worse, since it can fail silently (i.e. just not return the object). Of course, here that won't ever matter, but it's good habits that lead to good code.